# URL Rewriting On Asp .Net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

Im Using URL Rewriting with global.asax and sitemap

Everything works on pages like this: "mysite/AboutUs/"
But on pages that Im passing parameters to like this for example: "mysite/SomeProduct/12345"
When using sitemap.currentnode it returns null.

What should I do?

Comment: you should show us your code and rewriting rules firstly.

Comment: No problam, but I dont think its the issue, I need to know how to write the sitemap so it will recognize the page. For example /SomeProduct/{Name}. Which code do you need?

Comment: This is the sitemap node <siteMapNode url="Product" title=""  description="" resourceKey="1011"/>

Comment: This is the Gloabal.asax section for this page: routes.Add("Product", new Route("Product" + "/{ProductID}", new CustomRouteHandler("~/" + "Product" + ".aspx")));

Comment: And when Im using sitemap.currentnode on a page like this Product/123 it returns null